# What does JavaScript >> stand for?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm translating a JavaScript algorithm into PHP, and I ran into the symbol >>, and I have no clue what it means. It's hard to search Google for symbols, so can anyone tell me what it means?

Comment: When you need to find out the features of a language, it is best to search for keywords like "reference", "operator", "statement", followed by the name of the language. That would solve the problem of looking for symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [sign-propagating right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Many, many, languages have this operator.

Wikipedia has a good [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on the subject. My first link has a few examples and an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit shifting operator: 
http://www.contactor.se/~dast/fpl-old/language/shift.HTML

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct, but this may be of help to you: If x is positive then

```
x >> y
```

is the same as

```
floor(x / (2 ** y))
```

where 2**y is 2 raised to the power y.

E.g. `x >> 3` is the same as `floor(x / 8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise right shift

Looks like PHP has this operator too:

https://www.php.net/operators.bitwise