# What does the operator/math sign ">>" mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

I've seen this symbol used in math in some javascript functions: >>

I can't find reference to what it means?

The context would be something like:

```
(a*100)*(b*100) >> 8
```

Comment: It's a [bitwise shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Comment: [Bitwise Right Shift Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/5s9e947e%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does JavaScript >> stand for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436424/what-does-javascript-stand-for) and [>> in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437169/in-javascript) and many others.

Comment: as mentioned about it is a bitwise operator : Check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=javascript_bitwise_operators

Comment: apologies didn't come up when I searched here or in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [bitwise "Sign-propagating right shift" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

> Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the right, discarding bits shifted off.

Examples:

```
8          (1000)
8 >> 1 = 4 (0100)
8 >> 2 = 2 (0010)
8 >> 3 = 1 (0001)
8 >> 4 = 0 (0000)
```

Comment: Cheers, not something I've ever come across before, thanks for the point in the right direction.